# Why is linear regression so poor in training using PYMC3

Tags: linear-regression, pymc3

I am new to PYMC3. Maybe this is a naive question, but I searched a lot and didn't find any explanation on this issue.
Basically, I want to do a linear regression in PYMC3, however the training is very slow and the model performance on training set is very poor as well. Below is my code:

```
X_Tr = np.array([ 13.99802212,  13.8512075 ,  13.9531636 ,  13.97432944,
    13.89211468,  13.91357953,  13.95987483,  13.86476587,
    13.9501789 ,  13.92698143,  13.9653932 ,  14.06663115,
    13.91697969,  13.99629862,  14.01392784,  13.96495713,
    13.98697998,  13.97516973,  14.01048397,  14.05918188,
    14.08342002,  13.89350606,  13.81768849,  13.94942447,
    13.90465027,  13.93969029,  14.18771189,  14.08631113,
    14.03718829,  14.01836206,  14.06758363,  14.05243539,
    13.96287123,  13.93011351,  14.01616973,  14.01923812,
    13.97424024,  13.9587175 ,  13.85669845,  13.97778302,
    14.04192138,  13.93775494,  13.86693585,  13.79985956,
    13.82679677,  14.06474544,  13.90821822,  13.71648423,
    13.78899668,  13.76857337,  13.87201756,  13.86152949,
    13.80447525,  13.99609891,  14.0210165 ,  13.986906  ,
    13.97479211,  14.04562055,  14.03293095,  14.15178043,
    14.32413197,  14.2330354 ,  13.99247751,  13.92962912,
    13.95394525,  13.87888254,  13.82743111,  14.10724699,
    14.23638905,  14.15731881,  14.13239278,  14.13386722,
    13.91442452,  14.01056255,  14.19378649,  14.22233852,
    14.30405399,  14.25880108,  14.23985258,  14.21184303,
    14.4443183 ,  14.55710331,  14.42102092,  14.29047616,
    14.43712609,  14.58666212])
y_tr = np.array([ 13.704,  13.763,  13.654,  13.677,  13.66 ,  13.735,  13.845,
    13.747,  13.747,  13.606,  13.819,  13.867,  13.817,  13.68 ,
    13.823,  13.779,  13.814,  13.936,  13.956,  13.912,  13.982,
    13.979,  13.919,  13.944,  14.094,  13.983,  13.887,  13.902,
    13.899,  13.881,  13.784,  13.909,  13.99 ,  14.06 ,  13.834,
    13.778,  13.703,  13.965,  14.02 ,  13.992,  13.927,  14.009,
    13.988,  14.022,  13.754,  13.837,  13.91 ,  13.907,  13.867,
    14.014,  13.952,  13.796,  13.92 ,  14.051,  13.773,  13.837,
    13.745,  14.034,  13.923,  14.041,  14.077,  14.125,  13.989,
    14.174,  13.967,  13.952,  14.024,  14.171,  14.175,  14.091,
    14.267,  14.22 ,  14.071,  14.112,  14.174,  14.289,  14.146,
    14.356,  14.5  ,  14.265,  14.259,  14.406,  14.463,  14.473,
    14.413,  14.507])
sns.regplot(x=X_tr, y=y_tr.flatten());
```

[image]

Here I use PYMC3 to train the model:

```
shA_X = shared(X_tr)
with pm.Model() as linear_model:    
    alpha = pm.Normal("alpha", mu=14,sd=100)
    betas = pm.Normal("betas", mu=0, sd=100, shape=1)
    sigma = pm.HalfCauchy('sigma', beta=10, testval=1.)
    mu = alpha + betas * shA_X
    forecast = pm.Normal("forecast", mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=y_tr)
    step = pm.NUTS()
    trace=pm.sample(3000, tune=1000)
```

and then check the performance:

```
ppc_w = pm.sample_ppc(trace, 1000, linear_model,
                    progressbar=False)
plt.plot(ppc_w['forecast'].mean(axis=0),'r')
plt.plot(y_tr, color='k')`
```

[image]

Why is the prediction on the training set so poor?
Any suggestions and ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are showing the graph of `plt.plot(ppc_w['forecast'].mean(axis=1), 'r')`.  The code you posted actually produces a reasonable plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This model is doing a fine job - I think the confusion is over how to handle the `PyMC3` objects (thank you for the easy to work with example, though!). In general, `PyMC3` will be used to quantify the uncertainty in your model.

For example, `trace['betas'].mean()` is around 0.83 (this will depend on your random seed), while the least squares estimate that, for example, `sklearn` gives will be 0.826.  Similarly, `trace['alpha'].mean()` gives 2.34, while the "true" value is 2.38.

You can also use the trace to plot many different plausible draws for your line of best fit:

```
for draw in trace[::100]:
    pred = draw['betas'] * X_tr + draw['alpha']
    plt.plot(X_tr, pred, '--', alpha=0.2, color='grey')


plt.plot(X_tr, y_tr, 'o');
```

[image]

Note that these are drawn from the distribution of "best fits" for your data.  You also used `sigma` to model the noise, and you can plot this value as well:

```
for draw in trace[::100]:
    pred = draw['betas'] * X_tr + draw['alpha']

    plt.plot(X_tr, pred, '-', alpha=0.2, color='grey')
    plt.plot(X_tr, pred + draw['sigma'], '-', alpha=0.05, color='red')
    plt.plot(X_tr, pred - draw['sigma'], '-', alpha=0.05, color='red');


plt.plot(X_tr, y_tr, 'o');
```

[image]

Using `sample_ppc` draws observed values from your posterior distribution, so each row of `ppc_w['forecast']` is a reasonable way for the data to be generated "next time". You might use that object this way:

```
ppc_w = pm.sample_ppc(trace, 1000, linear_model,
                      progressbar=False)
for draw in ppc_w['forecast'][::5]:
    sns.regplot(X_tr, draw, scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.005, 'color': 'r'}, fit_reg=False)
sns.regplot(X_tr, y_tr, color='k', fit_reg=False);
```

[image]